# Getting the following error: default-src 'none'

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm making a game with a library called Processing.js. This library has two built in functions that allow me to save and retrieve information from a .txt file. But when I tried to use this functions to retrieve scores, it didn't work. I checked the console and found the following error message:

*Refused to connect to '[url]' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

I'm very new to web development and have no idea what this means.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advanced

Comment: have you looked up what `default-src 'none'`is and what it means?

Comment: @schroeder Yes, I have. As I understand it, it's the fallback URL for other directives (like style-src) to follow if they don't have a specified URL.

Comment: @schroeder What I don't understand is how I can change it to make the error message go away

Comment: @schroeder I think the problem is in the .txt file, because I tried retrieving it from somewhere else and the same error appeared